# Is there a way to return the HTML contents of a velocity template that includes all directives and conditions?

Tags: java, templates, velocity

```
<p>Title</p>

#if (condition)
<p>Some message</p>
#end
```

My java method looks something like:

```
**public String getTemplateContents(Context context, String template)** {
   StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
   Template t = Velocity.getTemplate(template);
   template.merge(context, w);
   String s = w.toString();
   w.close();
   return s;
}
```

Currently, s only returns the output:
`<p>Title</p>`

I would like it to output the whole vm template contents:

```
<p>Title</p>

#if (condition)
<p>Some message</p>
#end
```

I have also tried using the mergeTemplate method with no success. Please help.

Comment: What `ResourceLoader` class are you using? If you are using `StringResourceLoader`, you can get the content of your template using `StringResourceLoader.getRepository().getStringResource(templateName).getBody()`